# Add new Item to list mvc .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, entity-relationship

I'm trying to add a new item to an existent list in my MVC application, my problem that's I don't know the correct approach to do it.

I've done this so far:

My Customer code:

**Controller**

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    public CustomerBusiness customerBusiness { get; set; }

    public CustomerController()
    {
        customerBusiness = new CustomerBusiness();
    }

    //Some code that makes CRUD and more these methods

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ViewAllJobOfferts(int id)
    {
        var cust = customerBusiness.GetById(id);
        return View(cust.JobOfferts);
    }

    public ActionResult CreateJobOffert(int id)
    {
        var cust = customerBusiness.GetById(id);
        return View(cust);
    }

   /* [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateJobOffert(JobOffertModel jobOffert)
    {

        return View();
    }*/
}
```

I have a relationship **1 to n** between my entities Customer and JobOffert, and the method ViewAllJobOfferts works fine, but I got stuck when I try to add a new JobOffert.
I have a couple of questions, here we go:

- I must to create a controller special to JobOfferts, or control
  inside the CustomerController?
- When I try to create the view that will submit the form to new
  JobOffert I didn't know how to link the customer to this new
  JobOffert, f I try create a page using customer model, I do not have the JobOffert attributes and if I create using the JobOffert model, I dont know how make the link between these two objects. how must I do this?

**PS.: Here the code of both models:**

- [JobOffert Model](http://pastebin.com/RMKhcJML)
- [Customer Model](http://pastebin.com/XAjU36vd)

Answer (score 0):

> I must to create a controller special to JobOfferts, or control inside
>   the CustomerController?

Not necessarily, controller like other class should follow SRP (Single Responsibility Principle). In this case as long as CustomerController facilitating information related to Customer, it's completely fine.

> When I try to create the view that will submit the form to new JobOffert I didn't know how to link the customer to this new JobOffert, f I try create a page using customer model, I do not have the JobOffert attributes and if I create using the JobOffert model, I dont know how make the link between these two objects. how must I do this?

The link between the customer and JobOffer is as you defined One-to-Many and entities contains references to each other. E.g. You can find all JobOffer for a customer whose Id is 1024 by querying JobOffer table where customerID = 1024. Likewise each JobOffer is traceable by Customer reference in entity class.

Now about creating a new JobOffer for a customer this is how you can go about:

```
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
    public CustomerBusiness customerBusiness { get; set; }

    public CustomerController()
    {
        customerBusiness = new CustomerBusiness();
    }

    //Some code that makes CRUD and more these methods

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ViewAllJobOffersForCustomer(int customerId)
    {
        ICollection<JobOfferModel> model = customerBusiness.GetAllJobOffersByCustomerId(customerId);
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateJobOffer()
    {
        // Blank model object to accept values from user, 
        // you may like to create a view model based on UI needs.
        JobOfferModel jobOfferModel = new JobOfferModel();
        return View(jobOfferModel);
    }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult CreateJobOffer(JobOfferModel jobOffer)
     {
         // You get a filled object here that contains customer id and job offer details
         customerBusiness.CreateJobOffer(jobOffer);
         return RedirectToAction("ViewAllJobOffersForCustomer", new { customerId = jobOffer.CustomerId });
     }
```

Sample business service class:

```
public class CustomerBusiness
{
    public ICollection<JobOfferModel> GetAllJobOffersByCustomerId(int customerId)
    {
        // TODO: Fetch job offer details from persistent store

        // E.g.
        // dataContext.JobOffers.Where(x => x.CustomerId == customerId).ToList();

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CreateJobOffer(JobOfferModel jobOffer)
    {
        // TODO: Add job offer details in persistent store

        // E.g.
        // dataContext.JobOffers.Add(jobOffer);
    }
}
```

Modified entity classes:

```
public class JobOfferModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Acepted { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
    public DateTime JobDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerModel Customer { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public ICollection<JobOfferModel> JobOffert { get; set; }
}
```

So basically you will have a method in CustomerController that returns empty ViewModel or Model object. On view you will make customerId hidden. So that when form is posted it is mapped to correct customer along with JobOffer details. Once you have model object in HttpPost method you just need to insert an entry in JobOffer table (any persistent store) with customerId associated with it.

There are other nitty gritty but above typical approach will give you a good start I hope. Cheers